# How to get the id of current node in php

Tags: php, mysql, dom

I am trying to create a blog like website using php/mysql. In this site there is an admin panel from where i can create a post and send it to the db. In the index page I am retrieving these blog post and dynamically displaying them using `echo`. There is also a comment section in every post. The problem is I have to figure out to which post the comment belongs, for this I have given `id='{$row['post_id']}` to the form element for comments, which is the primary key in my post table.

Now the main problem is when I am submitting this form, I need the `id` of this form in a variable so that I can insert it in my db table, I have spent hours searching the web, I have also go through php/manual regarding DOM but the problem is still unsolved.

How can I get the value of `id` attribute for the current form element?

```
echo "<form action='#submitComment' id='{$row['post_id']}' method='POST' class='form form-inline'>";
echo "<input type='text' name='comment' placeholder='Write a comment here...' id='comment' class='form-control'>";
echo "<input type='submit' id='submit' name='commentForm' value='Submit' class='form-control'>";
echo "</form>";
```

Comment: You don't. Only `name` elements are submitted to the server. Use a `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="...">` to submit the value.

Comment: The id attribute on the form will not be sent across to your app. You need to create a new hidden form field with the name "id" and the value of you row. `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="{$row['post_id']}" />`. Try out http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Comment: Store the post id either in php session variable, or encode it in the url to which you send your data, or as mentioned by others earlier, have a hidden html control.

Comment: If you're not sure what data you are posting you can always do `<?php var_dump($_POST); ?>` to see everything you can from the super global.

Answer (score 3):

Add a hidden field to your form, like so:

```
echo "<input type='hidden' name='post-id' value='{$row['post_id']}'/>";
```

You can then access this when the form is submitted using `$_POST['post-id']`.

Comment: it should be $_POST['post_id'] not $_POST['post-id']

Comment: @Rahi No? The input name in my answer is clearly `post-id`.

Comment: Yeah,I realized later. I was going to edit my answer.